# Get Grails to generate relative path in its relative URL

Tags: url, grails, gsp

I have a web application that can be accessed either directly as http://host.foo.loc:8080/foo/ or via a secure reverse proxy as http://www.company.com/apps/foo/

By default, Grails will generate relative URLs with relative paths, for example:

```
<g:form action="bar">
```

will produce:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="post" >
```

This will be OK locally but the reverse proxy will not accept http://www.company.com/foo/bar (it's missing /apps/)

If I do:

```
<g:form action="bar" base=".">
```

it's fine. But I don't really want to specify it on each and every tag that generates a link.

The best way to deal with this would be to get Grails to generate relative paths in its relative URLs. Alternatively, I could live with setting a global "baseUrl" to "." but I don't know how to do that either.

Any idea ?

[edit] In fact, setting the "base" to "." doesn't work. The first page "/foo/controller/action" will generate the link as "./controller/nextaction" which the browser will translate as "/foo/controller/controller/action" => 404. I guess this is why they're using absolute paths: they're not paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never been able to make this kind of scenario work, so I always keep the proxied and unproxied context paths the same, i.e. I would put the app at `http://host.foo.loc:8080/apps/foo`.  You can have a multi-level context path like this in Tomcat by naming the WAR file `apps#foo.war`.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion. I had forced the URLs to be completely absolute so that I could filter them but there are so many places where a relative URL can hide that it's just not worth the effort. I'm switching the internal application context to match the external one and adapt what needs to be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

Add `grails.app.context = "/foo/bar"` to your `Config.groovy`.

Comment: `grails.app.context` only applies to `grails run-app` (and `run-war`), it doesn't affect a production deployment.  In the production case you need to use the mechanism provided by whatever servlet container you're using (e.g. for tomcat you name the WAR `foo#bar.war`).

Comment: That is not true. There are a couple of places where absolute paths are generated, i.e. the URLs for CSS and JS imports (grails-resources) and jQuery-AJAX and all kind of paths generated starting with "/"

Comment: Yes, and those paths are based on the context path at which the application is deployed.  That path is set by `grails.app.context` in development but supplied by the container in production.